# Gitlab CI: How to fail a pipeline while still running subsequent stages/jobs

Tags: gitlab-ci

I am trying to run some jobs in a "test" stage followed by one job in a "monitor" stage.
The trouble is if the unit tests fail in the test stage, the entire pipeline fails and it skips my job in the monitor stage altogether.

I can set the unit tests to allow failure, which lets the monitor stage run, but the pipeline will pass if the unit tests fail, and I don't want that.

How do I have the monitor stage run its job while still having the pipeline fail if the unit tests fail?

Here is the relevant configuration:

```
include:
  - project: templates/kubernetes
    ref: master
    file: /.kube-api-version-checks.yaml
  - local: .choose-runner.yaml
    ref: master
.run_specs_script: &run_specs_script |
  ./kubernetes/integration/specs/run-specs.sh $CI_COMMIT_SHA $TEST_NAMESPACE $ECR_BASE_URL/test/$IMAGE_NAME $PROCESSES ${UNIT_TEST_INSTANCE_TYPE:-c5d.12xlarge}

.base_unit_tests:
  image: XXX
  stage: test
  coverage: '/TOTAL\sCOVERAGE:\s\d+\.\d+%/'
  variables:
    GIT_DEPTH: 1
  script:
    - *run_specs_script
  after_script:
    - kubectl delete ns $TEST_NAMESPACE
  artifacts:
    when: always
    reports:
      junit: tmp/*.xml
    paths:
      - tmp/*.xml
      - artifact.tar.gz

unit_tests:
  extends:
    - .base_unit_tests
    - .integration

unit_tests_dependency_update:
  extends:
    - .base_unit_tests
    - .low-priority


unit_tests_dependencies_next:
  image: XXX
  stage: test
  allow_failure: true
  except:
    - web
    - triggers
  tags:
    - integration-green-kube-runner
  only:
    refs:
      - merge_requests
    variables:
      - $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME =~ /^hint\/upgrade/
  variables:
    GIT_DEPTH: 1
    DEPENDENCIES_NEXT: 1
    IMAGE_NAME: next
  script:
    - *run_specs_script
  after_script:
    - kubectl delete ns $TEST_NAMESPACE
  artifacts:
    when: always
    reports:
      junit: tmp/*.xml
    paths:
      - tmp/*.xml
      - artifact.tar.gz

unit_tests_datadog:
  extends:
    - .integration
  stage: monitor
  image: node
  variables:
    DD_API_KEY: XXX
  before_script:
    - npm install -g @datadog/datadog-ci
  script:
    - DD_ENV=ci DATADOG_API_KEY="$DD_API_KEY" DATADOG_SITE=datadoghq.com datadog-ci junit upload --service <service> ./tmp
  dependencies:
    - unit_tests
  when: always
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best solution, but you could add a dedicated stage after your monitor stage that only runs on_failure (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#artifactswhen) and returns an exit code.

```
fail_pipeline:
  stage: status
  image: bash
  script:
    - exit 1
  when: on_failure
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work as "allowed to fail" doesn't count as failure and therefore won't trigger this job. It would only trigger if previous job actually failed (red) and therefore would be useless